# Avoiding if statements for object creation

Tags: java, reflection, immutability

I've a legacy application that works with immutable objects which are doing some validation while they are created in each constructor. Every Object does his own validation, f. ex. length checks, range checks, etc.

The business Objects looks like:

```
public class MyObject {
   private FieldA fieldA;
   private FieldB fieldB;
   ...
}
```

The Objects are created by calling cobol server that loads the data... this code looks very dirty:

```
if (isFieldSet(response.getValueA())) {
   myObject.setFieldA(new FieldA(response.getValueA()));
}

if (isFieldSet(response.getValueB())) {
   myObject.setFieldA(new FieldA(response.getValueB()));
}

...
```

And because there are lot of objects there are also a lot of if statements.
I could improve it using reflection and create the classes dynamically.

```
myObject.setFieldA(createField(A.class, response.getValueA()));
myObject.setFieldA(createField(B.class, response.getValueB()));
```

This makes my code nicer but much slower as well. Does someone see any elegant ways to solve this Problem?

Regards,

Mike

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  Ugly code that works is still code that works.  What is the payoff for making this change?

Comment: Looks like a candidate for the [Factory Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

Comment: Yeah, you're right, the code is working and will work correctly the next years. But yeah... I think code should not only work.

Comment: Factory Method would be a Solution but I've more than hundred of these Immutable Value Objects

Comment: You might find that actually obtaining reflected elements, `Method`s and `Constructor`s etc. is quite expensive in terms of CPU cycles, but actually doing the `.invoke(...)` is not, since this is simply stacking the call, then doing the jump.  If you can, try making `createField` be clever about caching the things you obtain via reflection.

Comment: 'isFieldSet()' is checking if the value is != null and not an empty String.

Comment: with caching the Constructor I've currently a factor 2.5 that reflection is slower than 'new'. Not as bad as expected. This is tested on server hardware. On my PC I've a factor of 20.

Answer (score 0):

If I get it correct, you want to get rid of so many If statements. Wouldn't it be good if you use some template engine which accepts a response and returns an output accordingly? The beauty is you can have only one If statement in the template which drives the object creation logic based on the input response.
Try [Velocity Template Engine](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2001/jw-1228-velocity.html).